# ireports con netbeans no corre ayuda que puedo hacer

Tags: java

```
public void ed_generarreporte(){
            Connection con = null;
           DAOProducto daoProducto = null;
            daoProducto = new DAOProducto();
            daoProducto.getConeccion();
            con = daoProducto.con;
            try{
                JasperReport masterReport = null;
                try{
                    masterReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("report1.jrxml"));
                }
                catch(JRException e)
                {
                 System.out.println("Error Al Cargar El Reporte Maestro");
                }
                JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(masterReport,null,con);// error aqui al compilar
                JasperViewer jViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperprint,false);
                jViewer.setTitle("Reporte De Prueba- FERREMAX");
                jViewer.setVisible(true);
           }catch(JRException e){
            System.out.println("Error Generando Reporte" + e.getMessage());

        }
        }
```

el error al momento de compilar es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:138)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:57)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:421)
>     at Control.controlmenu.ed_generarreporte(controlmenu.java:93)   at
>   Control.controlmenu.actionPerformed(controlmenu.java:75)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

lo que se quiere lograr es generar un reporte en el cual muestre los datos de una venta

Comment: No podemos adivinar el error sólo viendo el código. Edita tu pregunta para poner cualquier traza o mensaje de error que tengas y explica qué quieres conseguir y qué falla.

Comment: Hola @Norma.P que tienes en controlmenu.java: lineas 75 y 93

Comment: JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(masterReport,null,con); linea 93

Comment: la linea 75 se invoca el metodo

Comment: Al parecer tu problema es que la variable `masterReport` es `null` o la segunda variable que mandas como `null` está generando la excepción. Te recomendaría validar esa parte mediante debug, quizás esté fallando esta línea: `masterReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("report1.jrxml"));`

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, por lo que se ve el error esta por el sistema no puede encontrar el documento Jasper, verificar la ruta de donde se esta obteniendo.

Lo otro yo en mi caso para obtener el jasper y compilarlo uso el método. compileReport

```
private byte[] ficheroJasper;
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path+rutaJasper);
ficheroJasper = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(report, params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(resulSet));
```

Donde

**report** : es el archivo jasper compilado

**param** : son los parametros definidos en el jasper variables a setear

**resulSet** : en caso que quieres mostrar informacion adicional como lista de algo.

**ficheroJasper** : el archivo devuelto en byte[]

saludos